# How to arrange two html buttons horizontally in a single line with equal width by completely fills the screen size

Tags: html, css

Here i want to use two buttons which cover the entire screen width and the buttons should have equal width. And alo there should not be any space between these buttons.

I tried with the following HTML and CSS codes but i didn't get what i expect;

**CSS**

```
#container
{
    width:100%
}         
#button1
{
    width:50%;
}
#button2
{
    width:50% 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <button id="button1">Button1</button>
  <button id="button2">Button2</button>
</div>
```

I tried the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XkhwQ/1/) here the buttons not covering the entire screen size also a small gap is there between these two buttons. How to tackle this issue? Thank you..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/XkhwQ/7/***

> Q1: buttons not covering the entire screen size

The reason(s) are:

1. The box-model. By default the widths are calculated exclusive of paddings. In order to be safe, you should first set the `box-sizing: border-box` and reset the paddings and margins.
2. The `container` is 100% of what? Better, set the width on parent i.e. `body`.

You can mitigate this by:

```
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; /* reset */
}
html, body {
    width: 100%; /* specify width on parent */
}
.container {
    width: 100%
}
button {
    width: 50%; /* make the children equal */
}
```

.

> Q2: also a small gap is there between these two buttons

The reason is:

The buttons are intrinsically inline elements and this means the white-space counts.

You can mitigate this in two ways:

1. Comment out the white-space.
2. Set the `float` on buttons.

***Example 1 (using comments)***:

```
<div class="container">
    <button>Button1</button><!--
    --><button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

***Example 2 (using floats)***:

```
.container > button {
    float: left;
}
```

The demo (http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/XkhwQ/7/) covers and illustrates both issues.

.

Answer (score 3):

Both of your buttons should have a width of 50% and be floated to the left or right

```
#button1, #button2
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="btn-box"><button id="button1">Button1</button></div>
    <div class="btn-box"><button id="button2">Button2</button></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

& CSS

```
#container{width:100%} 
.btn-box{display:block; width:50%; float:left;}
.btn-box button{display:block; width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo on button2 class.

```
#button2
{
width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply float to buttons and make them 50% width:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

#button1,
#button2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<style>
    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #button1,
    #button2 {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    background:#dbdbdb;
    }
    </style>


    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">

    <div id="button1">First Button Text</div>
    <div id="button2">Second Button Text</div>

    </div>


    </body>
```